# Ampps - addon domain

Tags: ampps

I just installed AMPPS but I am stuck at adding a domain. I added a domain as addon, and AMPPS created the directory for it in /www and shows me the list of domains (i.e. the root folder with the domain I created showing as a folder).  Ampps also added the entry into the hosts file (i.e. 127.0.0.1  domain.com) but I think it is missing a vhost setting somewhere.

The addon domain is mapped to the default site folder (www/) instead of the folder within the root that is created. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck with this problem for almost a day, both on my mac and windows. Fortunately, I found the fix and it is quite easy.

Go to AMPPS installation folder, open `conf` and create a new folder named `extra`.

For mac, this is the full path to create the folder `/Applications/AMPPS/conf`.

For windows, the full path is `C://Program Files (x86)/AMPPS/conf`

The existing addon domains will not resolve to their folder, but the new addon domains you create will resolve to their folder instead of root folder.

Answer (score -1):

You will just need to restart Apache. You can do this in the AMPPS panel or by restarting AMPPS completely.

Once it's done, you can try your addon domain name and it will point to its proper directory.

Comment: I have the same issue, but my vhost is correct and my host file also. but restarting apache or my pc nothing works. I also have this issue at work and can't develop for this sole reason.

Comment: Are you on a Mac or PC? This worked for my Mac. I can test if you you let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Windows if that's what you ment  with pc (a mac is also a pc)